# Send empty HTTP header with libcurl

Tags: curl, libcurl

I want to add an empty header in my HTTP packet. Something like:

```
Someheader:
```

But I see that libcurl does not support that. They propose a workaround by concatenating the empty header with another header:

```
"Someheader:\r\nheader1: value"
```

Does the latest libcurl offer another — more proper — way to send an empty header?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Per [an example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html) on the libcurl site, you can replace the colon with a semicolon. That will expand into an empty header. So:

```
Someheader;
```

will actually be sent as:

```
Someheader:
```

Comment: as I saw still not same like regular requests. in normally requests if empty still have one space before value but with that there is no space after : 
Someheader:here need to be a space